# Jquery replace li using index?

Tags: jquery

I need to replace a li, for example (NOTE: the IDs may not always be in order)

```
<ul>
<li id="first"></li>
<li id="second"></li>
<li id="third"></li>
<li id="fourth"></li>
<li id="fifth"></li>
</ul>
```

So say I want to replace id "third" with a new `<li>`, I know I can get the index with

```
$("li").index("#third");
```

And I can then remove it with

```
$("#third").remove();
```

How do I replace it with a new `<li>`?

I know the easiest solution is to simply replace the data *inside* the `<li>` but unfortuanately that isn't an option

Comment: [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) or [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#third').replaceWith('<li>Foo</li>');
```

for example.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using the [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method?

```
$('#third').replaceWith('<li>Hello world</li>');
```

Alternatively, you mention using the index; if you wanted to remove the 3rd list item, you could use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select the correct one, and then replace with, like this:

```
$('li').eq(2).replaceWith('<li>Hello world</li>');
```

Comment: thanks, i thought of index because I had assumed I would need the position

Answer (score 1):

All you really need is the [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) function.

Not sure what you think you need an `index()` for.